# SQL execution error

Tags: mysql

I try this query

```
INSERT INTO shop.product(prod_id,model,desc) SELECT product.id_prod,prod_lang.name,product.ref from product left join product_lang on product_lang.id_prod = product.id_prod
```

However I got this error

SQL execution error # 1065.Response from the database:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near') SELECT product.id_prod,product_lang.name,product.ref from' at line 1

Comment: Have you tried the subselect by itself?

Comment: INSERT INTO table (colums) VALUES (values)

Comment: `prod_lang` != `product_lang`

Comment: @Scott: No need for VALUES when you use `Insert into...select...`. See [**this**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: @RagingBull Ah, interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. `DESC` is a reserved keyword. Use backquote (``) for desc.
2. Change `prod_lang` to `product_lang` in the query.

Solution:

```
INSERT INTO shop.product (prod_id,model,`desc`) 
SELECT product.id_prod,product_lang.name,product.ref 
from product left join 
     product_lang on product_lang.id_prod = product.id_prod
```

**Note:**

It is a good practice to use backquotes for all columns eventhough it is not a reserved keyword.